# Group dicts and sum attribute

Tags: python

I have following list of dicts:

```
presets = [{'proportion': 1, 'filter': {'tagger_mood': ['sad', 'party']}},
{'proportion': 1, 'filter': {'vocal_instrumental': 1}},
{'proportion': 1, 'filter': {'vocal_instrumental': 2}},
{'proportion': 1.1, 'filter': {'tagger_mood': ['sad', 'party']}},
{'proportion': 1.1, 'filter': {'vocal_instrumental': 1}},
{'proportion': 1.1, 'filter': {'vocal_instrumental': 2}}]
```

I need to group them by `filter`, sum `proportion` and get:

```
{'proportion': 2.1, 'filter': {'tagger_mood': ['sad', 'party']}}
{'proportion': 2.1, 'filter': {'vocal_instrumental': 1}}
{'proportion': 2.1, 'filter': {'vocal_instrumental': 2}}
```

I made it like this:

```
presets = [...]
merged_filter = []
merged_proportion = []
for preset in presets:
    if preset['filter'] not in merged_filter:
        merged_filter.append(preset['filter'])
        merged_proportion.append(preset['proportion'])
    else:
        merged_proportion[merged_filter.index(preset['filter'])] += preset['proportion']
print([{'proportion': p, 'filter': f} for p, f in zip(merged_proportion, merged_filter)])
```

But definitely there is more efficient, beautiful and pythonic way to do it. Any suggestions?

Comment: This data is strange, is the vaue of `filter` always a dict of length 1?

Comment: I will note, there is nothing really *unpythonic* about your solution. The problem is that it is *inefficient*, because you are using lists and then checking each iteration if the item is in the list. Normally, you group with a dictionary, but your keys aren't hashable. Now, you can convert them to something hashable, but this makes everything more unweildy.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: because you can't order dicts, but you can order strings (which is related to your comment about keys not hashable)

Comment: `filter` could be mode complex, not only dict of length 1, for example `'filter': {'tagger_genres': ['dance', 'electronic', 'reggae', 'ambient', 'jazz', 'pop', 'rock', 'folk', 'classical', 'country', 'house'], 'bpm_from': 100, 'bpm_to': 120}`

Comment: The method should still work, provided your `filter`s are consistent order-wise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a "more pythonic" way (depending on your definition of pythonic):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> presets = [{'proportion': 1, 'filter': {'tagger_mood': ['sad', 'party']}},
... {'proportion': 1, 'filter': {'vocal_instrumental': 1}},
... {'proportion': 1, 'filter': {'vocal_instrumental': 2}},
... {'proportion': 1.1, 'filter': {'tagger_mood': ['sad', 'party']}},
... {'proportion': 1.1, 'filter': {'vocal_instrumental': 1}},
... {'proportion': 1.1, 'filter': {'vocal_instrumental': 2}}]
>>> [{"proportion": sum(i['proportion'] for i in g), "filter": f} for f,g in itertools.groupby(sorted(presets, key=lambda i: str(i['filter'])), lambda x: x["filter"])]
[{'proportion': 2.1, 'filter': {'tagger_mood': ['sad', 'party']}}, {'proportion': 2.1, 'filter': {'vocal_instrumental': 1}}, {'proportion': 2.1, 'filter': {'vocal_instrumental': 2}}]
```

A bit of explanation:

To group the elements in the list, we use groupby from itertools. However, groupby groups adjacent elements, so we need to sort the list by filter first. As sorting by dictionaries is not supported we translate each dictionary to string for sorting:

```
>>> list(itertools.groupby(sorted(presets, key=lambda i: str(i['filter'])), lambda x: x["filter"]))
[({'tagger_mood': ['sad', 'party']}, <itertools._grouper object at 0xffd6f5c8>), ({'vocal_instrumental': 1}, <itertools._grouper object at 0xffd6f988>), ({'vocal_instrumental': 2}, <itertools._grouper object at 0xffd6fb20>)]
```

As you can see, itertools.groupby returns a list of tuples, each consisting of the filter by which was grouped and a grouper object, which is an iterable over the items that were grouped. So last step is that we want to sum up the values of the proportion inside each of the grouper objects returned. This is easily done with sum:

```
sum(i['proportion'] for i in g)
```

where g is the grouper object.

Last step is to use dictionary comprehension to get again the dictionaries we want, with proportion being assigned the sum and filter being assigned the value that was grouped by:

```
[{"proportion": sum(i['proportion'] for i in g), "filter": f} for f,g in itertools.groupby(sorted(presets, key=lambda i: str(i['filter'])), lambda x: x["filter"])]
```

Comment: Nice, I was still struggling with an elegant way to merge the grouped dicts; not using the 'string' sorting key for the groupby does it.

Answer (score 2):

If the filter dictionaries are the same instances or have the same order, you can use the string representation of the filter dictionary as a key to group and tally the data in an indexing dictionary.  Then use the values of that dictionary as your merged list.

```
merged = dict()
for p in presets:
    d = merged.setdefault(str(p['filter']),{**p,'proportion':0})
    d['proportion'] += p['proportion']
merged = list(merged.values())

print(*merged,sep="\n")
{'proportion': 2.1, 'filter': {'tagger_mood': ['sad', 'party']}}
{'proportion': 2.1, 'filter': {'vocal_instrumental': 1}}
{'proportion': 2.1, 'filter': {'vocal_instrumental': 2}}
```

If a string version of the filter dictionary (or other hashable form) is not usable, you could write the sequential process like this:

```
merged = []
for p in presets:
    match = next((m for m in merged if m['filter']==p['filter']),None)
    if match: 
        match['proportion'] += p['proportion']
    else: 
        merged.append(p)
```

*Note that this may not cover the case of  list criteria that could be in different order and not be matched (e.g. ['sad','party'] vs ['party','sad'])*

Answer (score 1):

Yeah one way is to use the `collections.defaultdict` class. This class creates a dictionary that automatically creates a new entry for any key that is not already in the dictionary. We can use this to create a dictionary where the keys are the filter values and the values are the proportion values. We can then sum the proportion values for each key using the sum() function.

```py
from collections import defaultdict

presets = [
    {'proportion': 1, 'filter': {'tagger_mood': ['sad', 'party']}},
    {'proportion': 1, 'filter': {'vocal_instrumental': 1}},
    {'proportion': 1, 'filter': {'vocal_instrumental': 2}},
    {'proportion': 1.1, 'filter': {'tagger_mood': ['sad', 'party']}},
    {'proportion': 1.1, 'filter': {'vocal_instrumental': 1}},
    {'proportion': 1.1, 'filter': {'vocal_instrumental': 2}}
]

merged_presets = defaultdict(float)

for preset in presets:
    filter_key = tuple(sorted((k, tuple(v) if isinstance(v, list) else v) for k, v in preset['filter'].items()))
    merged_presets[filter_key] += preset['proportion']

result = [
    {'proportion': proportion, 'filter': {k: list(v) if isinstance(v, tuple) else v for k, v in filter_key}}
    for filter_key, proportion in merged_presets.items()
]

print(result)
```

the above code will give you output something like this.

```
[{'proportion': 2.1, 'filter': {'tagger_mood': ['sad', 'party']}},
 {'proportion': 2.1, 'filter': {'vocal_instrumental': 1}},
 {'proportion': 2.1, 'filter': {'vocal_instrumental': 2}}]
```